# Integration under the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Question: Prove that if $f$ is continuous in [a,b] and $g$ is monotone increasing and continuous from the right, then 
\begin{equation}
\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)=\int_{(a,b]}f(x)dg(x),
\end{equation}
where $dg=d\mu_g$, and $\mu_g$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by $g$.

///////////

I have no idea where to start the proof. Hope get an answer here.Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the singleton $\{a\}$ is a set of measure zero. (Maybe not a good hint)